# Angular mat-stepper creating x number of sliders in step 2 based on number selected in from previous step

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to create a stepper dialog with a dynamic number of sliders.

The first step allows you to select a number, the second step should have n sliders where n is the number selected in step 1. So far I get errors below (when selecting 2 as the number of sliders) and no sliders appear.

ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'allocation0'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203
ERROR TypeError: this._sliderInput is undefined
ERROR TypeError: endInputElement is undefined
ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'allocation1'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203
ERROR TypeError: this._sliderInput is undefined
ERROR TypeError: endInputElement is undefined

[image: 4 sliders should appear in step 2]

Angular template

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>Split Coins</h1>
<div mat-dialog-content>
    <mat-stepper orientation="vertical" [linear]="true" #stepper>
        <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup" label="Number of Party Members">
            <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                <mat-form-field color="primary" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-label>Party Members</mat-label>
                    <input
                        matInput
                        required
                        type="number"
                        formControlName="firstCtrl"
                        (ngModelChange)="numPartyMembers = $event">
                </mat-form-field>
            </form>
            <div>
                <button
                    mat-flat-button
                    matStepperNext
                    color="primary"
                    type="button"
                    (click)="onFirstStepClick()"
                    >
                    Next
                </button>
            </div>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step label="Allocate Percentage" [completed]="false">
            <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
                <mat-form-field *ngIf="allocations.length > 0" color="primary" appearance="outline">
                    <div *ngFor="let allocation of allocations; let i = index">
                        <mat-slider formControlName="allocation{{i}}" min="0" max="100" step="1" thumbLabel></mat-slider>
                    </div>
                </mat-form-field>
            </form>
            <div>
                <button mat-flat-button matStepperPrevious color="primary">Back</button>
                <button mat-flat-button matStepperNext color="primary">Next</button>
            </div>
        </mat-step>
        <mat-step label="Split Results">
            <!-- Add content for the final step if needed -->
        </mat-step>
    </mat-stepper>
</div>
```

Angular component

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-split-coins-dialog',
  templateUrl: './split-coins-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./split-coins-dialog.component.css'],
})
export class SplitCoinsDialogComponent {
  public numPartyMembers: number = 0;
  public allocations: any[] = [];
  public firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
  });
  public secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({});

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder, private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  public onFirstStepClick(): void {
    this.allocations = [];
    const numMembers = this.firstFormGroup.get('firstCtrl')!.value;
    if (numMembers !== null) {
      this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({}); // Reinitialize the form group
      for (let i = 0; i < +numMembers; i++) {
        let controlName = `allocation${i}`;
        console.log(controlName)
        this.allocations.push(controlName);
        this.secondFormGroup.addControl(controlName, this._formBuilder.control(100, Validators.required));
      }
      // Emit a value change event to trigger change detection
      this.secondFormGroup.updateValueAndValidity();
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
  }
}
```